# Count the number of times a letter is used

Tags: python, counter, frequency, letter

With this I not only need to count the frequency of the letters in a word, but I also need to spit out the unused letters.

```py
alphabetList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",\
    "l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]


def Checksums():
    for i in alphabetList:

        character = i
        myString = Phrase
        myList = []

        for i in myString:
            myList.append(i)

        myList = myList.sort()
        print myList

        count = 0
        for i in myList:
            if i == character:
                count = count +1
            else:
                continue
        print("There are ", count, " occurrences of ", character )


#input
Phrase = str(raw_input("Enter a Phrase: "))

Phrase = Phrase.lower()
# print (Phrase)
Phrase = Phrase.replace(" ", "")
# print Phrase

Checksums()
```

An example of input could be:

```
aaA cC D <br>
```

and the returning would be

```
"There were '3' occurrences of the letter 'a'"<br>
"There were '2' occurrences of the letter 'c'"<br>
"Only 1 'd'"<br>
"The remaining letters are unused": b, e, etc...
```

I tried to use the alphabet list and just cycle through that but I'm getting the following error:

> > TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: What part of the code should output the remaining letters?

Comment: Where do you get the TypeError? Please provide the traceback.

Comment: ``myList.sort()`` sorts the list in place and returns ``None``. All methods that modify mutables in place return ``None``.

Comment: I'll add on the print the remaining letters later, that's much easier than counting/freq, you can just compare 2 lists in the negative.

Full trace: https://pastebin.com/ymFPtwqg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `myList = myList.sort()` by `myList.sort()` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Using Python's [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to determine the missing keys, results in:

```
import string
from collections import Counter


def check(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.lower().replace(" ", "")
    phrase = Counter(phrase)

    for counts in phrase.items():
        print ("There were %s occurrences of the letter %s" % counts[::-1])

    missingCharacter = set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(phrase.keys())
    print("The remaining letters are unused: %s" % ','.join(missingCharacter))


check('aaA cC D')
```

Output:

```
There were 3 occurrences of the letter a
There were 2 occurrences of the letter c
There were 1 occurrences of the letter d
The remaining letters are unused: b,e,g,f,i,h,k,j,m,l,o,n,q,p,s,r,u,t,w,v,y,x,z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
alphabetList = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",\
"l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
def occurence_counter(phrase):
    unused_letters = ""
    for alphabet in alphabetList:
        count = phrase.count(alphabet)
        if count > 1:
            print("There are ", count, " occurrences of ", alphabet )
        else:
            unused_letters = unused_letters + alphabet
    print("The remaining letters are unused" + unused_letters)
Phrase = str(input("Enter a Phrase: "))

Phrase = Phrase.lower()
occurence_counter(Phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to simplify your code

First, to count the number of occurrences of each letter in string, use a dict:

```
d = {};
for c in myString:
     d[c] = (d[c]+1) if (c in d) else 1
```

Then to print the stats of each letter:

```
# used letters:
for k in d:
    print("There are ", d[k], " occurrences of ", k)


#unused letters
for o in range(ord('a'),ord('z')):
   k = chr(o)
   if not (k in d):
       print("No occurrence of ", k, " in string")
```

Or combined:

```
for o in range(ord('a'),ord('z')):
   k = chr(o)
   if not (k in d):
       print("No occurrence of ", k, " in string")
   else:
       print("There are ", d[k], " occurrences of ", k)
```